# Как создать событие изменения Count списка, приходящего из другой программы

Tags: c#, события

Имеется приложение, которое получает доступ к другой программе через библиотеку.В данной библиотеке есть функция получения определенного списка из другой программы. Необходимо провести некоторые действия, когда число элементов в данном списке изменится. Как можно создать событие, которое бы срабатывало при данном условии?

Comment: Какая сигнатура метода, который возвращает список?

Comment: Без передаваемых параметров - quik.Trading.GetTrades().Result; - результатом идет список, в котором и есть свойство Count

Comment: Интересует тип возвращаемого значения

Comment: Тип `Trade` :  List<Trade> tradeListNew = quik.Trading.GetTrades().Result;

Comment: Скорее всего в такой библиотеке есть событие, что список изменился. Если нет, то можно получить список, сохранить количество элементов и каждый раз при следующем получении списка сравнивать количество с предыдущим значением.

Comment: Так вот тогда и вопрос, когда именно получать список? Просто в другой программе он может измениться когда угодно и нам нужно отловить этот момент. Или создавать поток и каждые 5 секунд получать список и если его число изменилось, то что-то делать

Comment: По сути, данная библиотека с открытым кодом и я могут туда внести данное событие. Но опять же, как там записать его.

Comment: Если исправлять библиотеку, то можно использовать ObservableCollection вместо списка. Или просто добавить событие и вызывать его, когда список меняется внутри библиотеки.

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от функциональности библиотеки.

Если библиотека предоставляет в каком-либо виде сигнал об изменении списка, по можно подписаться на этот сигнал, и отправлять своё событие.

Если нет, то остаётся лишь поллинг: нужно перечитывать время от времени в фоновом потоке список из библиотеки, и сообщать событием, если есть отличия между старым и новым списками. Как часто производить поллинг и хранить ли результат, решать нужно вам, зная специфику вашей задачи.